# Python RandomForestClassifier - How to improve recall?

Tags: python, random-forest, precision-recall

I have an imbalanced data set and I am already using SMOTE to over sample it. I am getting a low recall value for 1 and I am trying a way to increase it and spread the error. I am fine with reduced overall accuracy.
The below [implementation](http://www.engineersbloc.com//collection/258/) by airbnb did the trick and the library is not open source it seems.

Is there anyway we can controll the fitting to improve the recall value.

Comment: Try modifying RF's threshold and see how that might affect your precision-recall curve

Comment: @Valilutzik, You suggest to fit a SelectFromModel and give a threshold before fitting the randomforest ?

Comment: Got it. min_impurity_split this was the one I was looking for

Comment: Well the default threshold for RF is 0.5 so you could have played with `predict_proba` to achieve that. Other than that, instead of using SMOTE, you can also instantiate RF with param: `class_weight="balanced"`and fit the RF on your unbalanced data, and see what you get